# Texmaker won't compile report anymore, even though nothing has changed!

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I was working with texmaker yesterday completely fine and everything was running fine but this morning I tried to run the report again and it just kept saying "sorry, but LaTeX did not succeed" and it didn't matter what I ran; BibTex, PdfLatex etc. it still kept saying "sorry, but XX did not succeed" and I just cannot figure it out.

I have reinstalled MiKTeX, I've updated all the packages on MiKTeX but it still won't work at all. Any ideas?! The message I get which doesn't stay on the screen so I have to print screen it every time to read it is:

```
Process started

Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/bibtex.log

Process exited with error(s)
```

The bibtex.log at the end of the log file name depends on if I ran pdflatex, or bibtex or latex etc.

It's extremely frustrating how it has literally stopped working overnight so any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us the log file.

Comment: Can you compile a minimal file from the command line?

Comment: Don't use texify, use pdflatex directly then you will get better error messages.

Comment: I'm not sure what any of these things means sorry I'm pretty new to Latex!! How do I show you the log file? I'll update the full file name above if that helps? How do I use pdflatex directly?

Comment: Where exactly is your document? The path looks strange, your document should not be in AppData or under miktex, that is where the installed latex lives, not your files.

Comment: I ran it what i thought was directly through pdflatex and ran through that fine but when running pdflatex-makeindex-bibtex it came up with the error "Miktex compiler drive did not succeed".

Comment: You open the file `\jobname.log` where `\jobname` is the name of your `*.tex` file. Copy it's contents and post them here. That's how you post your log.

Comment: Ah no my actual document is just in "my documents" and in some research folders. Do you mean you just want me to paste all my code I've written? (within reason)

Comment: Lets start from the beginning. We know you are using miktex. Which editor are you using? Do have you checked that latex actually works on your PC? Try starting a dos promt or what ever they are called in Win10 nowadays. And just run the command `pdflatex`, if installed correctly, then pdlatex should answer.

Comment: I use the texmaker studio editor, i know that! I use Miktex 2.9. Yes I've been using latex on this computer for about 2 years!!

Comment: It says: U:\>pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)

Comment: Ok so thats fine. Have a look in the TeXStudio Options menu → Configure TeXStudio. In the commands pane, what is listed in `pdflatex`? And BTW, under the Build pane what are your settings there?

Comment: It says: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
Build pan im not sure what you mean but the quick build is pdflatex - bibtex - pdflatex x2 - view pdf

Comment: That seems fine. What exactly is in your doc? Thy this simple doc and see if you can compile that: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello world\end{document}`, save it as `test.tex` somewhere under your normal documents, and compile it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61609/discussion-between-olivia-and-daleif).

Answer (score 1):

From discussion offf site, it seems to be caused by the actual file containing spaces in its name and poor error parsing in texstudio.

Renaming the file without spaces seemed to help. No idea why it would have worked earlier.

Comment: Windows pushed and actualization yesterday to my Windows 7 machine. Can't this be a probably cause for the poster?

Comment: @djnavas might be, what is actualization? Does not ring a bell